# Issue with method calling

Tags: javascript, class, methods

Hi I have this class with a method totalLength in it. However when I call the method I get

ReferenceError: totalLength is not defined.

Why is this happening?

```
class Streets {
constructor (length, name, size){
this.length = length;
this.name = name;
this.size = size;

}

totalLength() {
   let sum = (firstStreet.length + secondStreet.length + thirdStreet.length + 
   fourthStreet.length);
   console.log(`Total street length = ${sum}`);
   let avg = sum / allStreets.length
   console.log(`Average street length = ${avg}`);
 }

}


totalLength();
```

Comment: You are calling `totalLength` but no where reference `streets`. `totalLength` doesn't exist outside of `Streets` so it can't be just called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to instantiate an instance of your Streets than you can call the method on it.

```
let street= new Streets();
street.totalLength();
```

Ok, you will get further error `ReferenceError: firstStreet is not defined"`.